# How to play music from from local files in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I would like to play music that is on my pc on my Discordbot, here is the code i got:

```js
const discord = require ("discord.js")
const config = require('../config.json')

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    let general = "771078044466544640L";
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send("No estas en el canal de voz.");
    voiceChannel.join()
   .then(connection => {
      connection.play('C:\Users\juanchy\Desktop\DiscordBot\musica\micarta.mp3');
   });  
}      
module.exports.help = {
    name: 'micarta'
}
```

I was looking for help but all I found is to install ffmpeg and i did, to put that path into the variables and all that, then they suggest me to use `npm install discordjs/opus` and didnt work so i looked up at internet and did `npm i @discordjs/opus` but it shows errors when i put that in my prompt, so i havent gotten any results till the moment, I get to see my Bot like if it was playing music, but i cant hear anything, I would aprreciate a help here.

i didnt post the error, and this is the error:

"
sorry for not posting the error, this is the error i got:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\juanchy\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\juanchy\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v88-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown\opus.node --module_name=opus --module_path=C:\Users\juanchy\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v88-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3 --python=C:\Users\juanchy\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.3.2
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@15.12.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Users\juanchy\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v88-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown\opus.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/discordjs/opus/releases/download/v0.5.0/opus-v0.5.0-node-v88-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/discordjs/opus/releases/download/v0.5.0/opus-v0.5.0-node-v88-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for @discordjs/opus@0.5.0 and node@15.12.0 (node-v88 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/discordjs/opus/releases/download/v0.5.0/opus-v0.5.0-node-v88-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.12.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.12.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.15 found at "C:\Users\juanchy\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.1440) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS ************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS ************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:333:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\juanchy\\Desktop\\DiscordBot\\node_modules\\@discordjs\\opus\\prebuild\\node-v88-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown\\opus.node" "--module_name=opus" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\juanchy\\Desktop\\DiscordBot\\node_modules\\@discordjs\\opus\\prebuild\\node-v88-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3" "--python=C:\\Users\\juanchy\\.windows-build-tools\\python27\\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\juanchy\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.12.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\juanchy\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v88-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown\opus.node --module_name=opus --module_path=C:\Users\juanchy\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v88-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3 --python=C:\Users\juanchy\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\juanchy\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\@discordjs\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:85:20)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\juanchy\\Desktop\\DiscordBot\\node_modules\\@discordjs\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\juanchy\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v15.12.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.3.2
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\juanchy\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-12T06_42_48_824Z-debug.log
```

also you guys say my route is weird which is "C:\Users\juanchy\Desktop\DiscordBot\musica\micarta.mp3" thats the route i got in my pc to get the mp3 file, how should i replace it in order to make it not look "weird" i mean i thought i had to put the directory no? ty

Comment: "it shows errors" — What errors?

Comment: `'C:\Users\juanchy\Desktop\DiscordBot\musica\micarta.mp3'` — Try logging the result of that string literal.

Comment: already updated my question with the error it is showing.. thank you and sorry for not doing that before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code for my bot and I guess it should work for you too

```js
let VoiceChannel = await message.member.voice.channel;
//get the voice channel first. I guess you're doing it onMessage
let connection = VoiceChannel.join();
connection.play('audio.mp3', { volume: 0.5 });
```

Then check **if the bot has permission to speak in that voice channel**.
Then install `@discordjs/opus` properly.
Then the music should be playing

**Edit:**
Thanks for adding the error and as you can see you'll need `python`.

- First Install python from [python.org/downloads](https://www.python.org/downloads/) (I know we're using NodeJS but you'll need to install python too)
- Then Install windows build tools with

```js
npm install -g windows-build-tools
```

- Then Install node-gyp globally with

```js
npm install -g node-gyp
```

- Then try installing opus again and you should be fine

```js
npm i @discordjs/opus
```

Lastly, using `C:\Users\juanchy\Desktop\DiscordBot\musica\micarta.mp3` won't break the code but it'll make it harder to edit and you'll have trouble moving the code so put some time in learning Directories. you can use these resources to learn about directories

- [Microsoft - File paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats) (This is specially for Windows)
- [w3schools - HTML file paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)
- [Opensource - File paths and directories for Linux](https://opensource.com/article/19/8/understanding-file-paths-linux)

Comment: thank you a lot! i did correct my question with the code! so you can check it out!, i also mentioned there that i dont underrstand why you say my route is weird "C:\Users\juanchy\Desktop\DiscordBot\musica\micarta.mp3" thats the route i have to my mp3 file on my pc, isnt supposed to be like that? thank you  alot!